# Stretched elastic band shape

Tags: partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations

I have written a python code to obtain the minimum energy of a network of beads connected to one another via  springs (all with elastic constants $k=1$). The
rest length of each spring is zero, to simplify the code. The initial shape of
the band has rectangular with a triangular mesh. Each bead is connected to 6 nearest neighbors, except for those at the lateral borders (mostly with 5 nearest neighbors). The bottom and top lines are held fixed.

The initial configuration:

[image]

and the final configuration:
[image]

My question is: **How to obtain an analytical expression for the lateral curve?**

What I did was the discrete version of a homogeneous elastic band numerically. I think one should minimize the elastic energy of the homogeneous band:
$$
U= \frac 12\int(\nabla\vec u)^2dA,
$$
where $\vec u$ is the displacement from equilibrium.
By minimizing the elastic potential energy functional, one should get the
Laplacian equation for each component of $\vec u$,
$$
\Delta\vec u=0
$$
The boundary conditions are such that the bottom and top margins are held fixed (Dirichlet B.C.).
I think that on the lateral margins the normal displacement (or stress) $u_n=0$ in equilibrium (Neumann B.C.). So we have a mixed boundary conditions
problem.